# Detecting balls on contrast font using cv2

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am not a programmer, but a physicist. I want to detect balls in chain like this:
[image]

They helped me to write algorythm, do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_ball_positions(file_name):
    centers = []
    rrs = []

    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread(file_name)

    # Convert to HSV and keep the hue channel
    hue = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:, :, 0]

    # beads are red but on the blue side, so very bright hues
    # so threshold hue at 165 (out of 180)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(hue, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # apply morphology to fill beads and remove excess spots
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (6, 6))
    morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # get contours and enclosing circles
    contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
    circles = img.copy()
    num_circles = len(contours)

    rrs = np.zeros(num_circles, dtype=int)

    ave = 0
    for ii, cntr in enumerate(contours):
        center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cntr)
        cx = int(round(center[0]))
        cy = int(round(center[1]))
        rr = int(round(radius))

        centers.append((cx, cy))
        rrs[ii] = rr
        # draw enclosing circle over beads
        cv2.circle(circles, (cx, cy), rr, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # cumulate radii for average
        ave = ave + radius

    # print average radius
    ave_radius = ave / num_circles
    print("average radius:", ave_radius)
    print("number of circles:", num_circles)

    # save results
    cv2.imwrite('beads_thresh.jpg', thresh)
    cv2.imwrite('beads_morph.jpg', morph)
    cv2.imwrite('beads_circles.jpg', circles)

    cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
    cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
    cv2.imshow('circles', circles)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return {
        "centers": centers,
        "rrs": rrs,
        "image":img
    }
```

but because of glare it does not work good:
[image]

Instead looking for a software solution, I painted all balls to matte white color. But now i have another problem: I can't detect white balls on red font because of noise:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that `img_t = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
show(img_t)` is good solution

Comment: That's a good approach but unfortunately, the movement makes it difficult if not impossible to determine the ball boundaries with good precision. In fact, for the same reason, by using a threshold you kind of lose some information about them. If possible, I would recommend you to try to use an [adaptive threshold](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/12/adaptive-thresholding-with-opencv-cv2-adaptivethreshold/) to minimize that loss of information.

Comment: ``` img_pro = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img0_grey,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,21,5)
show(img_pro) ``` and get somethink like this. shorturl.at/jJKZ4 but it is still to noisly to detect balls

Comment: in principle, I don't really need these balls as circles, it's enough for me to know their coordinates, maybe there is a solution easier than looking for balls

Comment: motion blur: shine more light on the situation. see if you can tell your camera to use a shorter exposure time. -- finding light circles on colored background: `cv.cvtColor` to HSV space and then `cv.inRange` (any hue, low saturation, high value), then some erosion maybe. or you could see if SimpleBlobDetector works without any of that... or with that. -- ignore all the threshold and adaptive threshold stuff. it won't work.